# Xcode 12 Change the size of the navigation bar self.navigationController

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar

It's for a webview, I want the Navigation bar on top, But I want it very small. But no matter what value I put there is not working :(

For example, with this code I have the text in navigation bar red

```
let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.red]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
```

but trying to change the height let's say 8, 80 or even 800 don't work :(

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 80)
```

is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually after iOS 11 Apple does not allow us to customize the height of navigation bar. you can do that with custom navigation bar

```swift
// Before iOS 11
class MyNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

  override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 80)
  }
}
```

or creating a custom navigation controller

```swift
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 80)
  }
}
```

---

*Community Bug Reports*

[Subviews of UINavigationBar don't obey view frame height](https://openradar.appspot.com/32912789)

[sizeThatFits not working](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/79632#241436)

[#iOS 11 Xcode 9 Navigation bar height not changes](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/88202#274620)

---

**BONUS**

Check the gianfilippoci's [answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/88202?answerId=268909022#268909022) on the developer forum

Comment: Hi, Can we do a offset instead ? like top -8 or something like that

Comment: Or "creating a custom navigation controller" how do I make it appear this custom bar ? I can't get this to work

Comment: set your navigation controller's class as `MyNavigationController` in interface builder or whatever you're using to create navigation controller

Comment: I'm trying, but the class selection is empty :( see this pic screen https://i.gyazo.com/fd495a51ef58aa5954f43ebcc33eca00.png

Comment: select `Navigation Controller Scene` > type `MyNavigationController`(have to be your custom navigation controller class name)

Comment: It works. but when I try to attach a webview inside this class, the bar is translucent :(